# How to search folder name and delete sub folders, but not searched folder

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, directory, delete-file

I need a batch file that prompts the user for a file path, and the first 3 letters in the folder name. Then the batch goes and deletes all the folders and files in the folders with these 3 letters, but keeps the folder starting with the 3 letters. I got a batch file that deletes all files in folder and sub-folders, but I also need it to delete the sub-folders. Here was my code for deleting all files:

```
@echo off
set /p filepath=Path to Main Directory: 
set /p string=First Letters of Sub-Folders to be Cleansed: 
FOR /D %%G in ("%filepath%\%string%*") DO del "%%G\*.*" /q /s
echo Done
pause
```

Then I tried a lot of different ways to also delete sub folders of `%%G`. I got as far where it names the sub folders of `%%G` here:

```
@echo off
set /p filepath=Path to Main Directory: 
set /p string=First Letters of Sub-Folders to be Cleansed:
FOR /D %%G in ("%filepath%\%string%*") DO for /r /d %%i in (%%G\*) do del "%%G\*.*" /q && echo %%i
echo Done
pause
```

But when I try to add  `&& rd /s /q %%i` at the end it says file and path not found.

Comment: I think it may be a little confusing, I have a folder say named test. In it are exp1 and exp2. In exp1 there is a folder named test2 which has test.txt. I want a batch file that searches for exp in the folder name, then would delete test2 and test.txt and any other subfolders or files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to recursively look for folders in your "exp1" folder. You can simply use FOR /D to list the child folders and then use RD /Q /S to remove the entire folder hierarchy rooted on each child. Also, since all the child folders are being removed anyway, there is no need to do a recursive file delete.

```
@echo off
set /p filepath=Path to Main Directory:
set /p string=First Letters of Sub-Folders to be Cleansed:
for /d %%G in ("%filepath%\%string%*") do (
  del "%%G\*" /q
  for /d %%F in ("%%G\*") do rd /s /q "%%F"
)
echo Done
pause
```

Comment: Ok it worked, but I need something else in this code, right now it deletes every folder, but I want it to not delete sub-folders that start with my. Such as My documents and My Music. Can I do an exception in the for loop or can I say for every sub-folder that does not contain My?